# Двойные кавычки (кавычки в кавычках)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Имеется предложение, написанное в кавычках: "Исполнитель ОАО "Электронный паспорт". И вот как быть: по идее, в конце должны быть двойные кавычки, ведь в них взято и предложение в целом, и название ОАО, то есть, должно быть так: "Исполнитель ОАО "Электронный паспорт"". Или тут нужно внутреннее название брать в полиграфические кавычки, то есть так: "Исполнитель ОАО «Электронный паспорт»"?
Как правильно?

Answer (score 7):

Грамота. ру как-то давно объясняла: Если внутри слов, заключенных в кавычки, встречаются другие слова, в свою очередь заключенные в кавычки, рекомендуется (при условии, что для этого есть технические возможности) использовать кавычки разного рисунка: внешние – «елочки» , внутренние – „лапки“ (или – в текстах, набранных на компьютере, – "компьютерные кавычки") . Если же такой возможности нет, то закрывающие кавычки ставятся только один раз. Кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. Например:

Предпочтительно: работа В. И. Ленина «О карикатуре на марксизм и об „империалистическом экономизме“», ЗАО «Издательский дом „Комсомольская правда“», ООО «Компания „Металлинвест“».

Допустимо (если нет технической возможности использовать кавычки разного рисунка): работа В. И. Ленина «О карикатуре на марксизм и об «империалистическом экономизме» , ЗАО «Издательский дом «Комсомольская правда» , ООО «Компания «Металлинвест» .

Неправильно: работа В. И. Ленина «О карикатуре на марксизм и об «империалистическом экономизме»» , ЗАО «Издательский дом «Комсомольская правда»» , ООО «Компания «Металлинвест»» .

Comment: Есть какие то ссылки на нормативные документы, где прописано про "кавычки разного рисунка"?

Answer (score 0):

Корректно оформить либо так:

*«Исполнитель ОАО "Электронный паспорт"»*, либо:

*«Исполнитель ОАО «Электронный паспорт»*.

Конечно, можно наоборот:

*"Исполнитель ОАО «Электронный паспорт»"*;

*"Исполнитель ОАО "Электронный паспорт"*.

Ни в коем случае нельзя использовать две **одинаковые** закрывающие/открывающие кавычки **подряд**.

Можно использовать либо одинаковые кавычки, но убрать одну закрывающую, либо использовать кавычки разного рисунка. **Но рекомендуется использовать кавычки разного рисунка.**