# Допустима ли фраза "обернулся назад"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, плеоназм, речевая-избыточность

Часто встречаю в литературе (в том числе старой) следующие фразы: "сказал, обернувшись назад", "обернулся назад", "она обернулась назад" и т. д.

Скажите, корректно ли использовать подобное словосочетание? Разве "обернулся" не подразумевает, что человек и так смотрит назад?

Comment: Какой вывод вы сделали?

Comment: @oleedd я редко употреблял эту фразу (если только на автомате писал), но зато теперь понимаю, что это не будет ошибкой в рамках художественной литературы, поэтому никогда не буду указывать на это авторам. Мне важно было узнать именно допустимость использования фразы. Но краткий вариант без "назад", как мне кажется, выглядит чуть-чуть лучше.

Comment: Возможно, что "назад" используется для усиления фразы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фраза "обернулся назад", думаю, не просто допустима, а полностью соответствует нормам.

> [**ОБЕРНУТЬСЯ,**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x&help=1) -нусь, -нёшься; **св. 1.** Повернуть голову, туловище назад, в сторону. *Обернулся лицом к окну. Быстро обернулся на чьи-то шаги. Дирижёр обернулся на аплодисменты.* // Сделать полный круг вращения вокруг своей оси.

[**Обернуться**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) – повернуться в какую-то сторону.

Из словарных статей следует, что можно обернуться *на что-то, куда-то и как-то*. И это действие не обязательно направлено в противоположную сторону. Чтобы подчеркнуть именно эту сторону используется наречие "назад". В словарях плеоназмов "обернуться назад" не попалось.

Вы правы, это словосочетание довольно частотно (как в устной, так и в письменной речи), встречается и в старой, и в советской, и в современной литературе. В Нацкорпусе русского языка есть **179** примеров с *обернулся/-ась/-ись назад*, а также: **63** – *обернувшись*, **41** – *оборачивался/-ась/-ись*, **40** – *оборачиваясь*, **36** – *обернуться*, **19** – *оборачивается*, **8** – *оборачиваться*, **3** – *обернувшийся/-аяся*. И это только **389** случаев, в которых глагольная форма и наречие стоят рядом. Вот несколько в хронологическом порядке:

*Вдруг он остановился, как вкопанный, как будто молнией пораженный, и быстро потом **обернулся назад**, вслед прохожему, едва только его минувшему, ― обернулся с таким видом, как будто что его дернуло сзади, как будто ветер повернул его флюгер.* [Ф. М. Достоевский. Двойник (1846)]

*Наконец она сделала, с очевидным утомлением, два, три шага и остановилась. Потом… тихо **обернулась назад** и вздрогнула.* [И. А. Гончаров. Обрыв (1869)]

*Когда кончилась процедура поцелуев, Лариса, как разбитая, **обернулась назад** и попятилась...* [Н. С. Лесков. На ножах (1870)]

*Она ни разу, даже украдкой, **не обернулась назад**, чтобы увидеть Боброва.* [А. И. Куприн. Молох (1896)]

*Толпа глухо заволновалась, стоящие впереди **обернулись назад***... [А. А. Фадеев. Разгром (1925-1926)]

*Она дошла до калитки своего сада и **обернулась назад.*** [М. М. Зощенко. Возвращенная молодость (1933)]

*Путешественники **обернулись назад** и замахали волшебнику руками.* [Николай Носов. Незнайка в Солнечном городе (1958)]

*Почувствовав, что столкновения не произошло, Кнопочка открыла глаза и, **обернувшись назад**, увидела паровоз...* [Николай Носов. Незнайка в Солнечном городе (1958)]

*Панков спускается на землю, ставит чемоданы, смотрит вперед, потом **оборачивается назад**: никого не видно.* [Юрий Казаков. Легкая жизнь (1962)]

*Все **обернулись назад**, но ничего не увидели.* [С. Ольтин. Большая перемена // «Трамвай», 1991]

*...он **обернулся назад** и погрозил кулаком уплывающему серому фасаду...* [Виктор Пелевин. День бульдозериста (1991)]

*Подумав об этом, он **обернулся назад**, к Библиотеке.* [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

*― Древко! ― **обернувшись назад**, бесновато улыбаясь, крикнул Веня. ― Древко сюда!* [Захар Прилепин. Санькя (2006)]

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ и примеры!

Comment: Как ещё можно обернуться, если не назад и не к какому-нибудь предмету?

Comment: @oleedd Обернуться можно и на 360 градусов. Неважно, на кого или что направлено действие. Важно, куда – назад, а не вокруг своей оси.

Comment: То другое значение (сделать полный круг вращения вокруг своей оси). Про человека так никто не скажет. Не будет двусмысленности, обернулся назад или на 360°. Обернулся — это почти как оглянулся. В значение первого глагола не входит "посмотрел".

Comment: @oleedd  "...так никто не скажет".  "В значение первого глагола не входит "посмотрел"". Что это? Я нихт понимэйт!

Comment: Странно, здесь всё clear. Никто не скажет, что человек обернулся на 360°. Да и на 360° оборачиваются постоянно (*планета; стрелка часов*). Словарное значение слова "оглянуться": **обернуться** и посмотреть назад. Но комментарий был написан до прочтения этого, то есть понял это и без словаря.

Comment: Вдруг вспомнил про [это правило](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40766). Мне оно не нравится, но оно есть.

Answer (score 3):

Александр, я дополню ваш ответ, **причем не рассуждениями, а примерами.**

"Обернуться назад" говорят часто, так как это требуется **по смыслу**, вносит **определенность** в содержание текста. Поэтому он **никак не "дефолтное"**, к тому же оно **точно следует толковому словарю.**

Наречие "назад" опускается, если направление ясно **из предыдущего предложения** (контекста):

*Тут **сзади** тронули его за плечо. **Он обернулся**: парень в ватнике и морской фуражке выжидательно смотрел на него серыми глазами.* [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

*Тут за стенкой, в комнате дочери профессора, заиграл патефон фокстрот «Аллилуйя», и в то же мгновенье послышалось воробьиное чириканье **за спиной** у профессора. **Он обернулся** и увидел на столе у себя крупного прыгающего воробья.* [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

*Сейчас же его ущипнули через пальто **ниже спины**. **Он обернулся**. Плечистая и костлявая женщина лет сорока глядела на него жёлтыми глазами и вдруг принялась хмыкать, вытягивая губы трубкой, хихикать, ― прельщала.* [А. Н. Толстой. Черная пятница (1924)]

В этих примерах наречие "назад" выглядело бы **избыточной информацией.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Интересно, что во всех рассуждениях **о поворотах и градусах** нет ни одного примера из художественной литературы. В результате создается впечатление, что разговор идет  не об изящной словесности, не о языковой практике, а где-то в физической лаборатории изучаются **конструкции роботов.**

**Какое все это имеет отношение к языку,** трудно сказать. Наш язык не механический, употребление слов и словосочетаний связано с долгой традицией, оно фиксируется в словарях и в произведениях наших известных писателей.

Вот что нужно **изучать, анализировать и стремиться понять.** Но отвечающие вообще не касаются этой темы, не приводят ни одного примера, подтверждающего их точку зрения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138939/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Answer (score 2):

Идею для ответа подала Sharon своим дополнением к моему примеру.

Обернулся — это всегда назад. "Назад" не значит, что ровно на 180°. Так говорят, когда поворот более 90°, так как с такого угла можно уже увидеть то, что сзади. То есть между влево и вправо. Но можно обернуться к какому-либо предмету, то есть куда-то конкретно, при этом предмет тоже находится где-то сзади.

Пример:
*Вдруг слева послышался шорох. Он обернулся [влево] и увидел лису.*
Если что-то слева, то не скажут "обернулся влево". Разве это не режет слух? Скажут так: *повернулся влево*.
Тем более нельзя сказать "обернулся вперёд". То есть направление не может быть любым.

Вывод: это просто легальный плеоназм. То, что часто употребляется, становится легальным.

Comment: Это опять же сомнительные рассуждения, а нужны факты. Дайте еще пару ответов, может,  что-нибудь и докажете.

Comment: Что именно сомнительно?

Comment: Разве не факт, что нельзя обернуться влево?

Comment: oleedd, мне тут как бы некогда, может, вам еще кто-нибудь поможет разобраться. Пока!

Comment: *еще кто-нибудь поможет разобраться* — это значит, что вы тоже поможете. Надо: *ещё кто-нибудь **сможет** помочь разобраться*. Вот такую логическую ошибку вы допустили.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Мне помощь не нужна.

Comment: Меня эти дебаты запутали еще больше))

Comment: «Меня эти дебаты запутали еще больше» — Theej, вполне вас понимаю, я сам готов запутаться)) Чисто субъективно: при словах «обернулся назад» представляется, во-1-х, что обернувшийся до этого шёл впереди, во-2-х, что обернулся он «конкретно»: на 180º или почти на столько. Т. е. рассказчик увидел его лицо. Мне тоже трудно представить, что можно «обернуться назад» СО СВОЕЙ СОБСТВЕННОЙ ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ, поскольку личный «вперёд» у человека всегда с собой: куда повёрнуто лицо — там и перёд.

Comment: Хотя нет: скорее, обернувшийся шёл РЯДОМ с рассказчиком, и «назад», куда он обернулся, является таковым и для рассказчика. Потому что трудно, а сходу почти невозможно вполне понять, что для другого, иначе ориентированного человека, «перёд» и «зад» могут быть совсем не там, где они для тебя.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Теперь вас спрошу. В данном примере нет предмета, к которому можно обернуться. Куда ещё он мог обернуться, если не назад? Как ещё можно понять? Рассказчика здесь нет, представим человека, который идёт по дороге. Вот он и будет рассказывать, что он оборачивался.

Comment: oleedd, я неоднократно убеждался, что объяснять вам что бы то ни было бесполезно) Я только спрошу: с чего вы взяли, что действие происходит в небытии и что его точно нет, этого «предмета, к которому можно обернуться»? Вам не приходит в голову, что нормального человека ЧТО-ТО ДОЛЖНО ЗАСТАВИТЬ вертеться вокруг своей оси и что, следовательно, это «что-то», что его заставило, существует?

Comment: oleedd, ну а если «вот он и рассказывает» — тот самый человек, который шёл по дороге и оборачивался — каким же это образом «рассказчика нет»?))

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Имел в виду, что рассказчик не наблюдатель. Если следовать вашей логике, то, когда он оборачивается назад, он тоже оборачивается к предмету. Но он мог обернуться, чтобы посмотреть, не следят ли за ним. Но не так всё, он оборачивается либо к предмету, точно зная, где он, **либо в общем — посмотреть, что сзади, потому что он не знает, где оно именно и есть ли там оно в принципе**. Но не об этом спрашивал. Разве фраза "он обернулся" (без предмета) может означать, что он обернулся не назад? **Как ещё можно понять?**

Comment: «Как ещё можно понять?» — вам никак, вообще)) И адресуюсь я не к вам. Theej, «обернуться налево»: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search ...  «Обернуться направо»: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search ...  Есть и ещё примеры. Полагаю, если из контекста непонятно, что некто обернулся именно НАЗАД (а не направо или налево), то прибавить к слову «обернуться» слово «назад» вполне можно.

Comment: @ЕгорСальков С "налево" вообще лишь 3 примера, и то очень древние, может, когда-то так и говорили. С "направо" тоже древние, кроме двух. Очень сомнительно. Вот если вы приведёте такой контекст, то будет аргумент.

Comment: oleedd, повторяю: я обращаюсь не к вам. Зачем мне собеседник, не умеющий даже пользоваться НКРЯ?)) Примеров на «обернуться (обернулся) налево» там 4 (!) Ещё один пример содержится в ремарке пьесы «Пётр Первый» А. Толстого («Обернулся направо, НАЛЕВО. Приподнял бровь».) Пьеса 1933 год — это, конечно, очень древний пример)) Dixi, мне надоело)))

Comment: @ЕгорСальков А вас культуре общения не учили? Будьте вежливее. Вы случайно не хам? Вам не доставляет удовольствия хамить людям? Похоже на то. Тогда вы сайтом ошиблись. Подумаешь, нашли ещё один пример. И что с того? Это не 10. Просто ищу только в основном корпусе. Из этого вы сделали вывод, что не умею пользоваться? Умею там такие условия задавать, что вам и не снилось. Вы комментируете под моим ответом, если вам надоело, то свалите с него и комментируйте в другом месте. Или же будьте вежливым.

Comment: 1933 — это древний, но не очень. С того времени много чего поменялось.

Comment: Я бы нашёл вам примеры с «обернуться направо/налево» прямо из наших дней, но я по опыту знаю, что людей типа вас баловать вредно: они вежливость принимают за слабость, садятся на голову и свешивают ноги. А так-то ПРАВИЛЬНОМУ общению с такими меня учили — именно они и учили)))

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Вы меня с кем-то путаете. Даже и не представляю, как вежливость можно считать слабостью. Мне эти фразы режут слух, налево/направо не оборачиваются, а поворачиваются либо смотрят. И вообще, мне кажется, что "обернуться" связано с "обратно" морфологически (а обратно — это назад). Не забывайте про вежливость, знаю, что вы можете.

Comment: «Мне эти фразы режут слух, налево/направо не оборачиваются» — поскольку у множества пишущих (в том числе у признанных классиков) налево-направо вполне оборачиваются, то это допустимо и сейчас. А сугубо личное неприятие — очень неважный аргумент. «Мне кажется, что "обернуться" связано с "обратно" морфологически (а обратно — это назад)» — ничуть. «Обернуться» связано с «воротить». В неполногласной форме — «вертеть». Вертеть — это назад?))

Comment: Нет множества. Есть единичные случаи. И классик вроде бы один. Читал про "воротить", но слова морфологически вообще не похожи.

Answer (score 1):

В этом слове заложено значение "назад" как дефолтное. Если же в сторону, а не назад, то говорят куда:
*Обернулся лицом к окну.*
Если скажут, что он обернулся, то понятно, что он посмотрел назад.

Мне режет слух эта фраза, потому что "назад" подразумевается. Но не стоит забывать, что употребление плеоназмов не запрещено полностью, оно допустимо в художественных целях (например, для юмора).

Ещё есть такие плеоназмы, которые как бы становятся легальными из-за частого употребления, например "самый лучший". Похоже, что это один из них. Но не всегда это уместно, порой "назад" явно избыточно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

‟Обернуться назад” это определённо плеоназм (сочетание слов, где в значение одного слова уже входит обозначаемое другим словом), так как словом ‟обернуться” обозначают разворот туловища и головы так, чтобы можно было увидеть что-то за спиной, что стало причиной разворота — звук, прикосновение и т. д. То, что человек будет ‟оборачиваться назад”, ясно из любого контекста, так как это содержание регламента использования слова. Из контекста может быть не ясно то, по отношению к чему человек мог быть направлен до того, как обернулся, или то, что было у него за спиной до оборота, поэтому можно встретить сочетания ‟обернулся к окну”, ‟обернулся вслед” и т. д. В слово ‟обернуться” уже входит направление, поэтому нельзя сказать ‟обернулся влево”, ‟обернулся вправо”, ‟обернулся вперед”, ‟обернулся назад”.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138940/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-----).

Answer (score 1):

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Захотелось продолжить идею Jim Korbett. Он сказал о направлении движения. До этого думал лишь о градусе оборота.

Есть 4 направления: вперёд, назад, влево, вправо. Обернуться нельзя вперёд (это исходное положение). "Обернуться влево/вправо" — так тоже никто не говорит. Остаётся один вариант.

Когда говорят, что кто-то обернулся, то сразу понятно, что движение было по направлению назад, другого не дано. Он мог повернуться не полностью (180°), а на 135°. Но всё равно направление движения было назад, даже если он оборачивался к какому-либо предмету (предмет тоже сзади).
Не следует считать, что 135° — это обернулся, а 180° (противоположное направление) — это обернулся назад.

То есть обернуться — это повернуться по направлению назад или к какому-либо предмету (если о нём сказано), который сзади.

*Он обернулся* = *он повернулся лицом назад*. Что ещё эта фраза может значить?

Answer (score 1):

Theej, это тавтология только в том случае, когда ситуация совершенно исключает, что оборачивающийся может быть расположен *лицом* к условному наблюдателю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Безусловно уточнение необходимо,
сравните:
обернулся назад,
обернулся трижды вокруг себя,
обернулся в ее сторону,
и даже обернулся добрым молодцем.